# flask-admin: prettify json fields

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I really love the CRUD functionality of flask-admin.
Unfortunately I have not yet found a way to make json DB fields more readable.

JSON fields are displayed in the list view (and also in the edit view) as strings of text.

Can anybody give me any pointers where to start to prettify the list view (and later the edit view)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [column_formatters](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.column_formatters) to customize the looks of your field in the list view:

```
import json
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.view import ModelView
from jinja2 import Markup

def json_formatter(view, context, model, name):
    value = getattr(model, name)
    json_value = json.dumps(value, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
    return Markup('<pre>{}</pre>'.format(json_value))

class MyView(ModelView):
    column_formatters = {
        'my_json_field': json_formatter,
    }
```

Or you can use [column_type_formatters](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.column_type_formatters) to apply this style to all dictionary fields in your view:

```
import json
from flask_admin.model import typefmt
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.view import ModelView
from jinja2 import Markup

def json_formatter(view, value):
    json_value = json.dumps(value, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
    return Markup('<pre>{}</pre>'.format(json_value))

MY_FORMATTERS = typefmt.BASE_FORMATTERS.copy()
MY_FORMATTERS[dict] = json_formatter

class MyView(ModelView):
    column_type_formatters = MY_FORMATTERS
```

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968027/flask-admin-customize-datetime-view) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258668/flask-admin-how-to-change-formatting-of-columns-get-urls-to-display) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385080/flask-admin-display-enum-value-instead-of-name) of flask_admin formatters usage on the Stack Overflow but it wont hurt to have one JSON-specific.

`flask_admin.form.fields.JSONField` can be overriden to show pretty values in the input. [form_overrides](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_overrides) attribute is used for it:

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.view import ModelView
from flask_admin.form import fields

class JSONField(fields.JSONField):
    def _value(self):
        if self.raw_data:
            return self.raw_data[0]
        elif self.data:
            return json.dumps(self.data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
        else:
            return ''

class MyView(ModelView):
    form_overrides = {
        'my_field': JSONField,
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. The formatter works fine, but the indented structure is not displayed. I believe the tags <code><pre> need to be added. Any advice on how to do that?

Comment: @caliph You are right, I forgot about it. Fixed the answer. In short: you can use HTML tags in formatter functions but they need to be wrapped in the `jinja2.Markup` function.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for sharing!